# microphone noise issues Ubuntu 23.04 (lobster)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have tried so many apps like pulse and some scripts in order to cancel echo but nothing works. My laptop is thinkpad L13 gen2, When I observe input built-in microphone by settings it shows that microphone is waving that volume icon is going up and down in silent place. Could anyone help me please it's because it really disturbs me. I am a new user of Linux. Who has a same problem with me in recently please help me to get rid of this issue

Comment: Maybe the input volume on the microphone is too high. Have you tried decreasing the volume for the microphone so that the microphone is less sensitive?

Comment: I will check it now. You were right I decreased it and it seems that it works okay

Comment: Okay. I will make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input volume on the microphone may be too high.

If this is the case, you can decrease the volume for the microphone so that the microphone is less sensitive.

Comment: I have tried and it works but I decreased sensibility below the average about 25-30 out of 100

Comment: @Jason Yeah, sometimes audio engineers will use an attenuation cable for a microphone to cut down on the noise but all it really does is decrease the decibels. So you can essentially get the same effect by turning down the volume.